# How do I compare current variable value with previous variable value in batch script?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Based on this [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), it should be possible to do this with enabling delayedexpansion, but I am able to not get this to work.

I want to compare the current value that is in the variable with its previous value within a for loop. This is what I have so far.

```
@Echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "_var=first"
Set "_var=second" && Echo %_var% !_var!

For /R %%D in (  *_scan.log  ) do ( Set "path_only=%%~dpD"  &&  Echo --%path_only%~~~!path_only!-- )
```

Results Returned:

```
first second
--~~~W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\AAA11\--
--~~~W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\BBB22\--
--~~~W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\CCC33\--
```

Desired Results:

```
first second
--~~~W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\AAA11\--
--W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\AAA11\~~~W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\BBB22\--
--W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\BBB22\~~~W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\CCC33\--
```

How do I achieve the desired results? So I can compare current value with previous value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It is working

The behavior you are seeing is as described in the article link you provided: [s64: EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion command.

> When Delayed Expansion is in effect, variables can be immediately read using !variable_name!

The code you provided perfectly demonstrates this:

- **When Parsed:**       `%_var% == "first"`
- **When Executed:**   `!_var! == "second"`
- **When Parsed:**       `%path_only% == NULL`
- **When Executed:**   `!path_only! == "W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\AAA11\"`
                  loop 2:   `!path_only! == "W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\AAA11\"`
                  loop 3:   `!path_only! == "W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\AAA11\"`

##### Why `%path_only% == NULL` ?

At the time the file is parsed,
`%%D == NULL` therefore  `%%~dpD == NULL` therefore `%path_only% == NULL`

To compare the previous loop to the current loop you will need to store the previous loop's value and retrieve it.  You could do this with a simple variable.

I use `oldpath` in the example below

```
@Echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "_var=first"
Set "_var=second" && Echo %_var% !_var!
Set "oldpath=first_loop"

For /R %%D in (  *_scan.log  ) do (
   Set "path_only=%%~dpD"
   Echo --!oldpath!~~~!path_only!   
   Set "oldpath=!path_only!"
)
```

Results:

```
first second
--first_loop~~~W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\AAA11\--
--W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\AAA11\~~~W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\BBB22\--
--W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\BBB22\~~~W:\SCAN_LOGS\111\CCC33\--
```